# How exactly does the modal variable in Java Dialogs work?

Tags: java, dialog, modal-dialog

In the JavaDocs for [Dialog(Dialog,String,modal)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#Dialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) it says the following:

> modal - if true, dialog blocks input to other app windows when shown

If I understand correctly, if I pass a `true` argument to the constructor of a `Dialog`, will it just pause all the program until the user gives some kind of input to the application using this dialog?

For example suppose that we have this function in a class and a `JDialog` called `test`.

```
 public void function(){

  /*line*/   test t = new test(null, true); 

             while(true){
             System.out.println("print stuff");
        }
     }
```

If I call this function, it will pause, at `line`, then since the initial dialog is empty, if for example I close the dialog, then the while loop will be executed.

Is the phrase "the program pauses until the user gives an input **using** the **dialog**" is a somewhat correct description of what the modal variable is useful for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its partially correct, but.

But it isn't enough to call teh constructor, but you need to show the dialog after the constructor like this:

```
t.setVisible(true);
```

and yes, after this, the while loop does not start till the dialog isn't closed ( `setVisible(false)` )